# TFS and Project Server Synchronization

Tags: tfs, synchronization, project-server

I have got this trouble when I am setting up synchronization of TFS and Project Server:

> TF285010: The following user is not a valid Project Server resource: Andrei budkin. Add the Team Foundation user to the enterprise resource pool of the PWA instance and add it to the Team Members group. Then, add the user to the resource pool of the mapped enterprise project plan and publish the plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add a user to the enterprise resource pool using the PWA admin page. Go to the PWA home page and click on "Server Settings" on the left side and then click on "Manage Users". You need to add the user and make him/her at least part of the "Team Member" group.
2. Once you completed 1, you need to open your enterprise project using Project Professional and using the menu find the "Build Team ...." option and add the user as a member of the project. Then make sure to publish your project to Project Server.

Once you completed 1. and 2. the sync engine should be able to send new assignments or updates to existing assignments for that particular user.